# Using SHIFT+Arrows to select text in vim / MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim, textselection

One of the nicer features in MacVim is that it is possible to use the usual OS commands for copying and pasting text (namely command+C and command+V) in it.

This is especially nice in situations when you’ve worked in another editor just a minute before and your brain isn’t ready yet to advise your fingers on how to type the real thing.

However, there’s one thing my brain needs to do quite a little thinking on: It’s the text selecting mode. In non-vi editors, I’d use Shift+Arrow for this and trying this in MacVim doesn’t work. But on the other hand it does not look to me that Shift+Arrow is being used for anything else either. Is it possible to remap the keys in order to make this possible?

(Ideally, the editor would still be in insertion mode after having selected the text; that would spare some additional key strokes.)

Comment: Nice question, but I am tempted to suggest moving it to Super User as a program configuration questions. Very similar issues for emacs as discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36017/what-site-should-host-questions-about-emacs-keybinding on meta.

Comment: Do you want to be in insert mode after selection because you are replacing the selection (as when you would press `c` to clear the selection and enter insert mode), or for some other reason? It seems to me that if you have a selection, you're in visual mode, and therefore can't be in insert mode.

Comment: I wanted to stay in insert mode because I don’t want to leave insert mode unless it’s really necessary. In a ‘normal’ text editor when you select text, you’ll also stay in insert mode. It’s more for ‘transitional’ reasons; and as I said, copy and paste (and even save) via Command key works in insert mode, too.

Comment: @dmckee: Looking at the load of vim configuration tips on SO, I didn’t actually think of SU for this question. I wouldn’t mind if it’s being moved; but I think it’s been answered now anyway.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the manual:

> Text editors on Mac OS X lets the user
>   hold down shift+movement key to extend
>   the selection.  Also, pressing a
>   printable key whilst selecting
>   replaces the current selection with
>   that character.  MacVim can emulate
>   this kind of behaviour (by providing
>   key bindings and by setting 'keymodel'
>   and 'selectmode' to non-default
>   values) although it is not enabled by
>   default.  To make MacVim behave more
>   like TextEdit and less like Vim, add
>   the following lines to your "~/.vimrc"
>   (not .gvimrc) file:

```
if has("gui_macvim")
    let macvim_hig_shift_movement = 1
endif
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. Looks like it’s exactly the thing I’ve been looking for.

Comment: One minor annoyance though is that now I’ll need to press shift even in visual mode when using the arrow keys. Time to get used to ‘hjkl’…

Comment: what about non-macvim but rather vim?

Answer (score 7):

As a note to self and a neat hint for others:

Since SHIFT+Arrow selection and mouse selection now automatically starts `SELECT` mode, this means that it is apparently not as easy to make a `VISUAL` selection by using the mouse or arrow keys. (Even when already in `VISUAL` mode a mouse selection will still trigger `SELECT` mode.) Therefore, whenever one wants to apply commands to the selection, the following method helps.

- Select the text using mouse or SHIFT+Arrow
- Unselect by pressing `ESC`
- Press `gv` to automatically reselect the previous selection and trigger `VISUAL` mode

**Edit:** Same can be done using simply CTRL + g.

Comment: You could add `set selectmode=` to avoid entering SELECT mode by default. Use Ctrl+g to toggle between SELECT and VISUAL mode.

Comment: Personally, I like to be in selectmode when using SHIFT+arrow most of the time; but Ctrl+g is a good idea anyway. A bit simpler than `ESC, g, v`.

Answer (score 0):

in neovim, you just set selectmode to `mouse,key`:

```lua
    selectmode = "mouse,key",
```